Select through intermediate table in Laravel
I have three tables:

sites table (primary table)
listings table (it has sites_id as foreign key)
news table (it has listing_id as foreign key)

How to define a relation in Site Model to fetch all "news" related to specific site. I have tried the following but it's not working and returns 0 count.
$news = $site->news()->count();
public function news()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            News::class,
            Listing::class,
            'id',
            'id',
            'listing_id',
            null,
        );
    }

